# Toggling between chunk of input in iterm2 with "Alt + arrow left/right" writes "[D" instead jumping from chunk to chunk

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut, iterm

I just started to use `iterm2` on MacOS and find that it has really nice features especially for splitting terminal screen. However, when trying to toggle between chunk of input in with "Alt + arrow left/right" (which works in standard Terminal) writes "[D" instead jumping from chunk to chunk. Do you know how I could do to successfully jump from chunk to chunk?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Iterm2 Preferences Profile Keys. Click on "load Preset..." drop down-menu Natural text editing and chose "Natural Text Editing"

after that, the command "alt + arrow left/right" should function properly